# Solve $a(i,j)=1+a(i−1,j−1)+a(i,j−1)$ in sublinear time

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

$a(i,j)=1+a(i−1,j−1)+a(i,j−1)$

$a(1,j)=j$

$a(i,1)=1$

My thoughts:

The naivest way to solve this recurrence is to traverse all sub-problems in $O(i.j)$
Is it possible to get a closed form, something like sum of binomial co-efficients in pascals triangle.

for $i=2$,  $a(2,j) = j(j+1)/2 $

Answer (score 1):

For $i = 1$ we have $a(1, j) = j$.  For $i = 2$, as you note, we have $a(2, j) = j(j + 1)/2 = j + \binom{j}{2}$.  For $i = 3$, if you compute the first few terms, you get the sequence $1, 3, 7, 14, 25, \ldots$.  Based on the first two answers, it is natural to fit a cubic (or use the method of finite differences) and you are led to conjecture $a(3, j) = \frac{j^3 + 5j}{6} = j + \binom{j}{2} + \binom{j}{3}$.  I think what to do from here should be clear?